# Everything is green rectangles

Tags: intel-graphics, integrated-graphics

A computer belonging to a client has a strange problem, where occasionally the screen will go black, and green boxes will appear.

[image: Intel UHD 630 Graphics glitch green rectangles]

[image: Intel UHD 630 Graphics glitch green rectangles]

The screen consists of green rectangles, labelled with POS/RGB elements, e.g.

```
POS: (712, 600)
RGB: (0,0,0)
```

It looks like some sort of graphics developer/debug mode.

The graphics card identifies itself as a UHD Graphics 630.

Has anyone seen this phenomenon before?  Does anyone have any suggestions how to fix it?

Comment: There's probably a secret combo of keys you can press to invoke this mode, and if you have a couple sticky keys it might cause it to trigger when you press the magic missing key... I'm assuming it's a laptop, so you might need to unplug the keyboard header and re-seat it. Or plug in an external keyboard and disable the internal keyboard...

Comment: Also, is it using a GA driver rather than a beta driver? Might be worth a driver update.